# Magento 2 how to get products per website programmatically?

Tags: magento2, cataloginventory, multi-source-inventory

I want to know how to get the amount of products per website? I don't know if this exists, it should.

I was searching for a plugin or observer, but I cannot find it, under magento-catalog and magento-catalog-inventory.

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    ...
}

public function getProduct($storeId, $productId) {
    $product = $this->productFactory->create()
               ->setStoreId($storeId)
               ->load($productId);
    return $product;
}

public function getProductCollection($storeId) {
    $productCollection = $this->productFactory->create()
                          ->setStoreId($storeId)
                          ->getCollection()
                          ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $productCollection;
}
```

Here the **getProduct** function takes the store id and the product id as parameter and it runs the product model for that specific store.

And the **getProductCollection** function takes store id as parameter and returns the product collection for that specific store view.

Comment: I got it, but where can I execute this code? inside a Plugin, Observer? or override a Model from magento-catalog? can I do something like beforeGetProduct? also I wan't to do it in the backend Add Product button, can this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can get product price by website using below code

```
public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResourceModel
    ..... ) {
    .....
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->productResourceModel = $productResourceModel;
    ..... }



public function getProductPrice($productId, $storeId) {
    $productFactory = $this->productFactory->create();
    $product = $productFactory->load($productId);
    $product->setStoreId($storeId);
    return $product->getPrice(); 
 }
```

Comment: where can I execute this code? inside a Plugin, Observer? or override a Model from magento-catalog? is getProductPrice a plugin? can I do something like beforeGetProductPrice? also I wan't to do it in the backend Add Product button, can this work?

Comment: You should use this code inside helper and you can call helper whenever you needed